# MariaDB: group by does not count entries

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

```
(select a.id, b.gamesyouth+b.gamesadult as numofgames
from tusplayer a, tusplayerbasic b
where a.id = b.playerid and b.gamesyouth+b.gamesadult > 400)
union all
(select a.id, count(*) as numofgames
from tusplayer a, tuslineup b, tusgames c
where a.id = b.playerid and b.fussballdeid = c.fussballdeid and c.kickoff > '2020-10-14'
group by a.id)
order by id
```

it selects the number of games from 2 different tables.
It returns something like:

```
id           numofgames             
187          3                      
188          623                    
188          3                      
189          3                      
190          700                    
190          3
```

So e.g. id 188 and 190 have 2 entries, 187 and 189 only one.

Now I want to have the complete sum for both tables over id.
SQL:

```
select id, numofgames from ((select a.id, b.gamesyouth+b.gamesadult as numofgames
from tusplayer a, tusplayerbasic b
where a.id = b.playerid and b.gamesyouth+b.gamesadult > 400)
union all
(select a.id, count(*) as numofgames
from tusplayer a, tuslineup b, tusgames c
where a.id = b.playerid and b.fussballdeid = c.fussballdeid and c.kickoff > '2020-10-14'
group by a.id)
order by id) as rotz
group by rotz.id
```

But it returns only

```
id           numofgames             
187          3                      
188          623                    
189          3                      
190          700
```

188 must be 626 and 190 must be 703.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a sum :

`select id, sum(numofgames) ...`

Using group by without an aggregate function (count, sum, mean...) would just pick one row per group.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by/

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works! But why do I have to as an additional sum()?
Isn't group-by meant to count up several entries?

Comment: Using `group by` without an aggregate function (count, sum, mean...) will just pick one row per group. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group-by/

Comment: Please add some explanation **to your answer** such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, sum(x)
FROM tableA
GROUP BY id
UNION ALL
SELECT id, sum(x)
FROM tableB
GROUP BY id
```

Will result in 2 rows, because that's what `UNION ALL` does do.
If you only want one total you wil have to do:

```
SELECT id, sum(x)
FROM (
   SELECT id, sum(x) as x
   FROM tableA
   GROUP BY id
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, sum(x)
   FROM tableB
   GROUP BY id
) y
GROUP BY id
```